# Fatal Error: Allowed Memory size, while installing Auth in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, composer-php

I have installed Laravel using Hostinger Auto Installer. Now I am trying to install the Auth UI using this command: `composer require laravel/ui:^2.4`.

I also tried removing the version from the end of the command. It is showing:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size.

[image]

Please let me know how can I get rid of this issue.

Comment: Please share more details, like the current version of PHP or Composer (later versions work better than older). Also, keep in mind that you should never run `composer require` on any other system than your own development machine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require laravel/ui:^2.4
```

Comment: this is also creating the same error.